# Difficulty creating annotation script in python

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

I was trying to make an annotation tool in python to edit a large csv file and generate a json output, but being a newer programmer, I have been facing a lot of difficulties.

I have two csv files that I generated and then got a list of rows and columns that I wanted to match from one file: 
[filtered list of columns and rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUigc.png)

And the other file has a list of outputs that I wanted to match it with and gather the specified data entry: [raw outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5i9W.png)

For example, I would want to print the data in row 6 from column Q5.3 alongside the original question and then specify if it is good or bad. If it is bad I want to be able to add a comment.

I would like to generate a json file that compiles this in the end. I tried to write the code but it was complete garbage, I guess I was hoping to be able to understand how to properly implement and just became really confused.

Any help would be really appreciated!

The output should go through all the specified data and print: 
Question Number,
Question,
Response,
Annotate as Good or Bad,
If Bad then able to add comment,
Continue to next data piece, 
When done generate a json for data

Thank you :)

My attempt:

```
import csv
from csv import reader
import json

csv_results_path = 'results.csv'
categories = { '1':'Unacceptable', '2':'Edit'}

# Checking the outputs (comment out) 
''''
print(rows)
print(columns)
'''

'''
# Acquire data from specifed row, column in responses
# Example row 6, column '12.2'
'''



def get_annotation_input():
    while True:
        try:
            annotation = int(input("Annotation: "))
            if annotation not in range (1,3):
                raise ValueError
            return annotation, edited_comment
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter 1 or 2") 


def annotate():
          annotator = input("What is your name? ")
          print(''.join(["-"]*50))
          print("Annotate the following answer as 1-Unacceptable, 2-Edit")


          with open("annotations.json", mode='a') as annotation_file:
              annotation_data = ('annotator': annotator, 'row_number':, 'question_number': , 'annotation' : categories[str(annotation)], 'edited_response': }
              json.dump(annotation_data, annotation_file)
              annotation_file.write('\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    annotate()

with open('annotations_full.csv', 'rU') as infile:
              response_reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
              responses = {}
              for row in response_reader:
                  for header, response in row.items():
                      try:
                          responses[header].append(response)
                      except KeyError:
                          responses[header] = [response]
rows = responses['row_number']
columns = responses['question_number']
print(rows)
print(columns)
```

I was successfully able to get a list of the rows and columns that I wanted, however, I am having difficultly accessing the data in another csv file using the row and corresponding column to display and annotate. Also, when I attempted to write code to allow a field for an edited response if '2' is specified, I faced many output errors.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What you are asking is too much for one question. You should target specific single problems and ask about them. Don't be afraid to show code there may be something in there that can be worked with.

Comment: @KlausD. thank you both for the willingness to help, I will edit the response above to include what I had written, just worried it will look foolish but oh well lol

Comment: @PaulRooney I was only allowed to tag on per comment